# Australia transit visa

Tags: transit-visas, australia, applications, poland

I am a third party country nationals residing with resident permit in Poland. I have a visa to NZ however I want to transit from Australia by flight. I need a transit visa. I should go to vfs for biometric. I searched in immigration Australia but I confused. Can I go to vfs in Poland to do this? I know polish citizens do not need such  thing but I do as a foreign nationals. If vfs in poland cannot do t his which vfs shall I go? Should I go to another country to do it? Unfortunately there is no email to contact with immigration Australia!!

Comment: There is a link to the application process here https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/transit-771 According to the Australian Embassy, Poland website, Visa processing is undertaken electronically through the online ‘eVisa’ service, or by processing centres in Australia, or by the immigration office at the Australian Embassy in Berlin, Germany for clients resident in Poland, Lithuania and the Czech Republic https://poland.embassy.gov.au/wsaw/Visas_and_Migration.html

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure the embassy process the biometric. I  though vfs does all of that. So shall I ask embassy in berlin?

Comment: Have you tried applying online?

Comment: applying online is another issue sir. After completing it it will tell us that go to biometric due to our nationalities. Here I dont know where to go.

Comment: Also it is written here this email is not for visa inquiries! They are really complicated!https://germany.embassy.gov.au/beln/contact-us.html

Comment: It’s not complicated. Apply online. It will tell you where to go and what to do.

Comment: If your email is in relation to a visa, citizenship or customs enquiries, the Embassy is unable to provide a response.  There is no Biometrics Collection Centre in Germany. If you are in Europe and have received a requirement to provide biometrics, the nearest Biometrics Collection Centre may be in France or Greece. Further information is available at https://www.vfsglobal.com/australia/france/ and https://www.vfsglobal.com/australia/greece/.

Comment: Then it seems you've answered your own question @AhmadTurani. That's the same information we can see. So it looks like you have to go to France or Greece to give biometrics. The only way to know for sure is to do what Traveller said, apply and they'll tell you where to go.

Comment: Ok  thanks...........k

Answer (score 1):

If your email is in relation to a visa, citizenship or customs enquiries, the Embassy is unable to provide a response. There is no Biometrics Collection Centre in Germany. If you are in Europe and have received a requirement to provide biometrics, the nearest Biometrics Collection Centre may be in France or Greece. Further information is available at vfsglobal.com/australia/france and vfsglobal.com/australia/greece.